# Check if folders name starts with certain string

Tags: c++, filesystems

Hello so basically what i want is to loop through all folders in a given directory and find a folder which contains 4p in it´s name

```
for (const auto& folderIter : filesystem::directory_iterator(roaming))
{
    if (folderIter.path() == folderIter.path().string().contains("4p") != std::string::npos)
    {
        filesystem::remove(folderIter.path());
    }
}
```

But this code does not work

Comment: Please explain the idea behind `if (folderIter.path() == folderIter.path().string().contains("4p") != std::string::npos)`.  I don't understand what you're trying to do there.

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean?  What is your question?

Comment: Sit down and discuss `if (folderIter.path() == folderIter.path().string().contains("4p") != std::string::npos)` with [your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Explain to the duck what each part of the code does and how it gets you closer to your goal.

Comment: you are comparing a path ( a string) with the result of a contains (a bool), which you in turn to the "not contained" position of string (a size_t type I think). what do you think happens in this line? what do you want to achieve by comparing these different types?
please explain what this 3-way comparison is supposed to do, in your eyes. the line makes no sense at all.

Comment: sorry, I edited the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you told:

> im trying to find a folder which starts with the name 4p. Nothing more

Does this meet your demands?:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int
main ()
{
  std::vector < std::string > _strings;
  // adding some elements to iterate over the vector
  _strings.emplace_back ("4p_path");
  _strings.emplace_back ("4p_path1");
  _strings.emplace_back ("3p_path");
  _strings.emplace_back ("4p_path2");
  _strings.emplace_back ("2p_path");
  _strings.emplace_back ("4p_path3");

for (const auto & p:_strings)
    {
      std::string first_two = p.substr (0, 2);// 0 = begin, 2 = end
      if (first_two == std::string ("4p")) // I assume 4p as suffix
    {
      std::cout << "4p\n";
    }
      else
    {
      std::cout << "not 4p\n";
    }
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Since you said that I have to find exact folders that have `4p` suffixes, I should add this one:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main()
{
    std::vector < std::string > _Folders;
    std::string path = "F:\\MyMusicProjects";// your directory
    // get the name of all folders and add it into folders vector
    for (const auto& entry : fs::directory_iterator(path)) {
  _Folders.emplace_back(std::string(entry.path().filename().string()));
    }
    // iterate over folders
    for (const auto& p : _Folders)
    {
        // p variable is the folder name and we compare it to check wheter it starts with 4p or not
        if (p.substr(0, 2) == "4p")
            std::cout << "found\t" << path << "\\" << p << "\n";
        else
            std::cout << "was not 4p\t" << path<< "\\" << p << "\n";

        // don't forget, p is the folder name, to get full path as string:
        // std::string fullPath = path+"\\"+p;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why this works is pretty obvious, but I'd replace *Does this meet your demands?:* With a very brief explanation because answering a question with a question makes the answer look weak. Also there are quicker ways to do this such as `find` and testing the returned position against zero and, if C++20 is available, calling `starts_with`.

Comment: sadly not what i want is to loop throught all the folders in a given directory and find a folder wich contains the 4p in the name

Comment: @B4nny, to get the folder name with `4p` suffix or anything else, you should already iterate over the folders. I just thought the problem is about getting the first 2 digits and comparing it. I see you can't explain your problem accurately because of your English. 

Just to be sure, do you want to get all the folders that their names start with `4p` word, right?

Comment: yes i want to basically check for the folder i marked in this screenshot http://prntscr.com/26vur8i

Comment: Okay, @B4nny. I'm going to edit the answer.

Comment: @user4581301 I've been through the same :D I should not say any word here

Comment: Well I would have just made a new question or delete this post because this was completely off. so what do you mean with update, I edited the post and you reverted it.

Comment: @B4nny, I made it. Just check it. If it solves your problem, don't forget to mark as solved.

Comment: thank you so much<3 it worked. But how can i mark it as solved i´m new to stackoverflow

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: FYI, `std::string(entry.path().string().substr(path.size()+1,entry.path().string().size()))` can be greatly simplified to just `entry.path().filename().string()`

Comment: @RemyLebeau, yesterday I was dozing while writing that :D I'm going to edit now